# At which layer should exception be caught?

Tags: java, exception

I have implemented a `Queue` and then a wrapper around it called `ImplementStackUsingQueue`.
Note - my question has nothing to do with accuracy or logic of implementation. Its only concerned with exception handling.

Queue implementation looks like

```
 public synchronized boolean add(int x) {
        if (currentSize == maxSize) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The queue is full: front size: " + rear);
        }

        queue[rear++] = x; // USE.
        rear = (rear + 1) % maxSize;     // NEXT.
        currentSize++;

        return true;
    }
```

The wrapper which uses this queue to implement a stack looks like:

```
  public void push(T x) {
        queue2.add(x);
        queue2.addAll(queue1);
        queue1 = queue2;
        queue2 = new LinkedList<T>();
    }
```

Now my wrapper, as of now, would rely on the underlying `Queue` to throw `IllegalStateException`.
My question is - is it good practice to rely on underlying components to throw exceptions OR is it worth duplicating exception handling condition `currentSize = maxSize` in `ImplementStackUsingQueue` and deal with exceptions before control goes to underlying layers ?

Comment: You do not show the documentation for the underlying Queue. Is throwing the exception part of its documented and unit tested functionality?

Comment: Its throwing exception as documented, but just curios why does this info a requirement for my question ?

Comment: The wrapper class should depend only on the documented and tested functionality of the underlying class, so that it cannot be broken by mere implementation changes. On the other hand, there is no reason to duplicate any of that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This topic is highly opinion-based, but there some consensus created over the years. One of them is ["Don't use exceptions for flow control"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)

For the code posted it would make more sense to just return false if it was not possible to add the element to the queue.

Now, to your question "is it good practice to rely on underlying components to throw exceptions"? **No** if the exception is being thrown to control flow.

"is it worth duplicating exception handling condition currentSize = maxSize in ImplementStackUsingQueue and deal with exceptions before control goes to underlying layers?"
No, the underlying level should just indicate if it could add the element to the queue or not:

```
public synchronized boolean add(int x) {
    if (currentSize == maxSize) {
        return false; // indicate in the javadocs when the false is returned
    }

    queue[rear++] = x; // USE.
    rear = (rear + 1) % maxSize;     // NEXT.
    currentSize++;

    return true;
}
```

It is hard to know what "push" is doing, since queue1 and queue2 could be modified or used elsewhere. If it is possible to isolate changes to the queues, then it should be ok for "push" to return false if it was not possible to add the element to the queue. If the queue doesn't accept null elements, then you could return null if it was not possible to push the element onto the queue, otherwise, return the element pushed. But note that it would be perfectly fine for "push" to throw exceptions. For example, it could throw a NPE if queue2 is null.

Again, this is highly opinion-based, so take my opinion with a grain of salt.

Comment: I have never understood the meaning of "Don't use exceptions for flow control" as currently promulgated. Exceptions *are* flow control, with a data side channel. When this dictum first appeared over 20 years ago what it meant was "don't use exceptions as `goto's` within a single method", and believe me I've seen code that did that. The dictum as used nowadays appears to me to be basically meaningless.

Comment: I hear you. In my mind, exceptions are branches to use case. Something like "I have to call my manager". Once the exception is handled, then the use case can continue/be restarted.